# Flex Spark List only Shows the last variable of an Array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I want to display the variables from an Arraycollection on a sparkList. But the List always shows the last variable only. Here is the code.

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

[Bindable]private var arc:ArrayCollection;

private function price(event:Event):void {

  var arr:Array='[web response]';
  for(var i:int=0; i < arr.length; i++){
  if((arr[i]['SalesPrice'] >= 0) && (arr[i]['SalesPrice'] <= 100)) {

  var string:String=arr[i]['InventoryId'];
  var array:Array=new Array(string);
  arc=new ArrayCollection(array);
  trace(arc);
  }
  }
    }

  ]]>
  </fx:Script>

 <s:List id="myList" dataProvider="{arc}" />
```

Got the output on trace, but I need to display it as a list. Any help

Comment: That code is totally unreadable, which is probably the main reason why it's hard to track your mistake. Other than that it looks like you're creating a new ArrayCollection with one item for each item in your original collection, overwriting the previous one on each pass in that loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your logic is not quite right.
In your scripts

> arc=new ArrayCollection(array);

is not correct for list; instead of that just use

> arc.addItem(array);

so your code becomes;

```
var arr:Array = '[web response]';
arc = new ArrayCollection();
for(var i:int=0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if((arr[i]['SalesPrice'] >= 0) && (arr[i]['SalesPrice'] <= 100)) {
        var string:String=arr[i]['InventoryId'];
        var array:Array=new Array(string);
        arc.addItem(array);
        trace(arc);
    }
}
```